# RESTful API request in python [ tensorflow serving ]

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-requests, tensorflow-serving

OS: Window 10

Tensorflow: V2

I used Tensorflow serving with docker as in this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uabNEQlpGM8

The code in powershell:

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving

mkdir tf_test
cd .\tf_test\
ls
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

Set-Variable -Name "TESTDATA" -Value "$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata"


docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two tensorflow/serving 

Get-Alias curl
Remove-Item alias:curl

curl  -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict  -d '{\"instances\": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}'
```

And by removing alias as he mentioned in the video I got the output of the request [in the powershell]

```
curl  -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict  -d '{\"instances\": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}'


>>
{
    "predictions": [2.5, 3.0, 4.5
    ]
}
```

Now I want to make the same API request in python script

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 
import json
# defining the api-endpoint  
API_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict"


#curl  -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict  -d '{\"instances\": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}'
# data to be sent to api 

data = {'instances':[1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}

# sending post request and saving response as response object 
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
# extracting response text
pastebin_url = r.text 
print("The pastebin URL is:%s"%pastebin_url)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
The pastebin URL is:{ "error": "JSON Parse error: Invalid value. at offset: 0" }
```

status code = 400  Bad Request

What wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried using `json=data` instead of `data=data` when making the request with `requests.post(...)`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = json.dumps(data))`